# How to make GDX Freetype work for iPhone development?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, freetype

I am trying to port my game from Android to iOS using LibGDX + RoboVM. RoboVM is set up successfully and I can test in an iPhone simulator.

I tried to follow the instructions on this website:
[Khela Interactive](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ybefSRltnwMJ:www.khelainteractive.com/porting-libgdx-game-iphone-via-robovm-part-2/%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl). However, I cannot find the `libs > iOS` folder and  `robovm.xml`.

How do I set up FreeType for iOS development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

In Project Gradle under iOS -> dependencies, add:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
```

Comment: Thanks. For others, if you build for iOS-MOE, change `compile` to `natives`. Tested on iOS 11.